My script doesn´t let me add contributors to my github repositorys
I have 15 repositorys, all of them with the name "21-051-(numberOfTheGroup)" where numberOfTheGroup is a number that depends of the number of the group. I have an .xlsx document that have gmail and number of the group of the members of each group.
I made this script, i want to take the emails of the .xlsx and the number of group, and add that emails as contributors of each repositorys (obviusly, only add the email to the repository of his group).
I made the script in Javascript with node.js and other version in python, but it doesn´t work in any of two options. In both cases send me the error 404 {"message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "docs.github.com/rest/collaborators/…"}. All the configurations in github and in the script are okay for me, i saw the documentation in github and other posts to do the script and all of them do the same thing i did, but it doesn´t work.
I will let the code here if somebody knowns what is the problem.
Python code:
import pandas as pd
from github import Github

# Token de acceso a GitHub
token = "Here i put my github token"

# Autenticación en GitHub con el token de acceso
g = Github(token)

# Leer el archivo Excel (.xlsx)
datos = pd.read_excel("Lista_Mails.xlsx")

# Iterar sobre cada fila del archivo CSV
for index, fila in datos.iterrows():
    grupo = fila["Grupo"]
    correo = fila["Correo"]

    # Obtener el nombre del repositorio correspondiente al grupo
    nombre_repositorio = f"24-051-{grupo}"
    
    try:
        # Obtener el repositorio
        repositorio = g.get_repo(f"SantiBoero1/{nombre_repositorio}")

        # Añadir al correo electrónico como colaborador
        try:
            repositorio.add_to_collaborators(correo, "maintain")
            print(f"Correo {correo} añadido al grupo {grupo} en el repositorio {nombre_repositorio}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error al añadir colaborador {correo} al repositorio {nombre_repositorio}: {str(e)}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al acceder al repositorio {nombre_repositorio}: {str(e)}")

Javascript code:
const { Octokit } = require('@octokit/rest');
const fs = require('fs');
const xlsx = require('xlsx');

// Token de acceso a GitHub
const token = 'Here i put my github token';

// Crear una instancia de Octokit con el token de acceso
const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: token,
});

// Leer el archivo Excel (.xlsx)
const workbook = xlsx.readFile('Lista_Mails.xlsx');
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
const datos = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

// Iterar sobre cada fila del archivo Excel
datos.forEach(async (fila) => {
  const grupo = fila.Grupo;
  const correo = fila.Correo;

  // Obtener el nombre del repositorio correspondiente al grupo
  const nombreRepositorio = `24-051-${grupo}`;

  try {
    // Añadir al correo electrónico como colaborador
    await octokit.repos.addCollaborator({
      owner: 'SantiBoero1',
      repo: nombreRepositorio,
      username: correo,
      permission: 'maintain', // Cambiar a 'pull' si se desea un rol de solo lectura
    });

    console.log(`Correo ${correo} añadido al grupo ${grupo} en el repositorio ${nombreRepositorio}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error al añadir colaborador ${correo} al repositorio ${nombreRepositorio}: ${error.message}`);
  }
});

I read all the documentation of Github, see other post here in stack overflow but i could´t find what is the problem
